# Reset kafka LAG (change offset) within consumer group in Kafka-python

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I found this where I reset my LAG with the kafka-consumer-groups.sh tool [How to change start offset for topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791268/how-to-change-start-offset-for-topic?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but I am needing to reset it within the application. I found this example, but it doesn't seem to reset it. [kafka-python read from last produced message after a consumer restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237311/kafka-python-read-from-last-produced-message-after-a-consumer-restart?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) example

```
    consumer = KafkaConsumer("MyTopic", bootstrap_servers=self.kafka_server + ":" + str(self.kafka_port),
                             enable_auto_commit=False,
                             group_id="MyTopic.group")
    consumer.poll()
    consumer.seek_to_end()
    consumer.commit()

    ... continue on with other code...
```

Running `bin\windows\kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group MyTopic.group --describe` still shows that both partitions have a LAG. How can I get the current-offset to "fast-foward" to the end?

```
TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                             HOST             CLIENT-ID
MyTopic         0          52110           66195           14085           kafka-python-1.4.2-6afb6901-c651-4534-a482-15358db42c22 /Host1  kafka-python-1.4.2
MyTopic         1          52297           66565           14268           kafka-python-1.4.2-c70e0a71-7d61-46a1-97bc-aa2726a8109b /Host2  kafka-python-1.4.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want this:

```
def consumer_from_offset(topic, group_id, offset):
    """return the consumer from a certain offset"""
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=broker_list, group_id=group_id)
    tp = TopicPartition(topic=topic, partition=0)
    consumer.assign([tp])
    consumer.seek(tp, offset)

    return consumer

consumer = consumer_from_offset('topic', 'group', 0)
for msg in consumer:
    # it will consume the msg beginning from offset 0
    print(msg)
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to "fast forward" the offset of consumer group, means to clear the LAG, you need to create new consumer that will join the same group.
the console command for that is:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <brokerIP>:9092 --topic <topicName> --consumer-property group.id=<groupName>
```

In parallel you can run the command to see the lags like you described, and you will see the lag  wiped.

Comment: I don't see how adding another consumer will end up causing it to reset? I'm looking to programmatically reset the the LAG.